# How to compare two HexCodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following `div` element, which contains **hex code** for a multiplication symbol.

```
<div>&#215</div>
```

Now in JavaScript I wish to do something like this

```
multiply = document.querySelector("div");
if (multiply.textContent == "&#215")
   //do something
else
   //something else
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is not a hex code. It is decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode`:

```js
let multiply = document.querySelector("div");
let isEqual = multiply.textContent == String.fromCharCode(215);
console.log(isEqual);
```

```html
<div>&#215</div>
```

But you can also just use the character as a string literal:

```js
let multiply = document.querySelector("div");
let isEqual = multiply.textContent == "×";
console.log(isEqual);
```

```html
<div>&#215</div>
```

Comment: It *is* a character -- just not the one you may have on your keyboard. If you look closely to my second snippet, the character is the special one -- not the normal "x", but "×" You can search for character codes by entering "unicode" in your search. For instance [multiplication unicode](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiplication+unicode)

Answer (score 0):

You could entities encode it (but missing `;`):

```
const entities = s => s.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, i => `&#${i.charCodeAt(0)}`);

if (entities(multiply.textContent.trim()) === "&#215")
   console.log('do something')
```

Your want need to `.trim()` it and perhaps pick a better selector than a `div`